# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Core Warning Message: Module 'ffmpeg' already loaded Filename: Unknown Line Number: 0 Backtrace

Tags: php, codeigniter, ffmpeg

Getting the following error in live

" 
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning
Message: Module 'ffmpeg' already loaded
Filename: Unknown  Line Number: 0
Backtrace:".

But i did not receive this error in local host. I am using codeigniter 3. Need Some help..

Comment: Error message is pretty clear. You're trying to load a module that's already loaded. Check your php.ini

Comment: Please tell me the total process of doing that.

Comment: in application/config/config.php at Error Logging Threshold - set it to 1 or 2. run your app. then check the log file in application/logs .

Comment: ok the logging might help but this probably has nothing to do with codeigniter - heres one link that might help explain it http://www.somacon.com/p520.php

Comment: How could i update php.ini in webserver?

Answer (score 6):

At last i can get rid of that error code.

First open index.php file from your codeigniter base_url folder. Then set the value 0 in display error. That's it..

```html
switch (ENVIRONMENT)

 case 'development':
  error_reporting(-1);
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
 break;
```

Comment: Its not solving the problem. Its just hiding it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Using php vs 7.1. i had same problem in the upper version

Answer (score 0):

in your case error would be hidden from viewers but the problem still consisting and this is just the cause of php version that you are using for hosting apps you have to login to the cpanel and search for php version set that to 5.5 and make that default too.
Hope its helpful.